# Execute SQL Job base on file modified data

Tags: sql-server, automation, ssis, sql-job

I have several SQL Jobs which are all scheduled to run at a certain time of the day. These Jobs generally execute SSIS packages which fetches the source data on a different server.

In some cases the SQL Jobs would run regardless if the source data has been updated, in which case I need to manually run.

I would like to automate the execution of the SQL Jobs but I am not sure which route to take.

Can I use a Script Task in SSIS to look at the modifiction date of files located on a different server?
Should I use File Watcher?

I would obviously then have to set my SQL Jobs to run every couple of seconds to check modification dates, would this eat up a lot of resources?

I'm using MS SQL 2014.

Comment: SQL Agent won't let you schedule jobs more frequently than every ten seconds. If you need something responsive to modified files then you probably want to have an external process (such as a Windows Service) that monitors the file system for changes and then pushes them into SQL Server.

Comment: In this situation if you really wanted it to remain within SQL Server you can create a job that is always running (ie starts automatically) and use `waitfor delay` to schedule it every second or two.